# How to build an indicator from source?

Tags: wingpanel

I already tried as described here:
https://elementary.io/de/docs/code/getting-started#building-and-installing-with-cmake

it simply does not show up.

I tried to use this hello world example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606264/simple-appindicator-with-vala-application-under-elementary-os

which leads to the following errors:

```
app-indicator:13536): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(app-indicator:13536): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(app-indicator:13536): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(app-indicator:13536): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(app-indicator:13536): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GdkWindow'

(app-indicator:13536): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_param_spec_object: assertion 'g_type_is_a (object_type, G_TYPE_OBJECT)' failed

(app-indicator:13536): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_class_install_property: assertion 'G_IS_PARAM_SPEC (pspec)' failed

(app-indicator:13536): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GdkScreen'

(app-indicator:13536): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(app-indicator:13536): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_default_colormap: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(app-indicator:13536): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_colormap_get_visual: assertion 'GDK_IS_COLORMAP (colormap)' failed
```

I compile with:

```
 valac --pkg appindicator-0.1 --pkg gtk+-3.0 app-indicator.vala
```

Comment: Do you get an error message when you run the build? Or, does the build succeed but the indicator doesn't appear when you run it? If you launch the indicator from terminal, do you get any error messages?

Comment: no error messages. i think there is just something i do not get about the whole process. how can i launch the indicator from terminal?

Comment: You can launch the application with `./app-indicator` there should be a window and an indicator that appear.

Answer (score 1):

I still cannot say what the problem was, I tried now after a few months and everything works as it should.

A big thank you goes out to [Ryan DeBeasi](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/792/ryan-debeasi) !

For documentation:

**How to build an indicator from source?**

1. Install the pre-required packages

   > sudo apt-get install libappindicator-dev
   >
   > sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
2. Create a new file called "IndicatorExample.vala"
3. Paste the [Ubuntu Indicator Example](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Vala_Example) code in it
4. Compile with

   > valac --pkg appindicator-0.1 --pkg gtk+-3.0 IndicatorExample.vala
5. Launch with

   > ./IndicatorExample

Comment: when compiling the sample inducator, what am I doing wrong? valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg glib-2.0 --pkg wingpanel Indicator.vala error: program does not contain a static `main' method Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)